# content Revision History moving database?

Tags: mongodb, database

I keep a content revision history for a certain content type. It's stored in MongoDB. But since the data is not frequently accessed I don't really need it there, taking up memory. I'd put it in a slower hard disk database.

Which database should I put it in? I'm looking for something that's really cheap and with cloud hosting available. And I don't need speed. I'm looking at SimpleDB, but it doesn't seem very popular. rdbms doesn't seem easy enough to handle since my data is structured into documents. What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: Is it the disk space you are worried about? Because if you do not access the collection at all, it will not take up memory (as in RAM) in MongoDB.

Comment: Yes but I am using a cloud host. They charge me the for how much I store regardless of whether or not it's in memory.

Comment: What exactly is 'cloud hosting' supposed to be? How big is your data that storage is really a concern (>>1TB)? How much money can you spend? Most importantly: if it's data size you care about, how should the database make a difference? Maybe you want to consider delta compression? If it's storage size you care about, compressed folders would help?

Comment: @mnemosyn my data is around 2 gigs currently and going up. Delta compression is definitely worthwhile but for now just want to find a cheaper storage solution. I just don't want to store on a database optimized for benchmarks when speed isn't important at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how often you want to look at this old data:

Why don't you mongodump it to your local disk and mongorestore when you want it back.

Documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools)

**OR**

Setup a local mongo instance and clone the database using the information [here](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21268149)

Comment: I want to be able to access it and query it just like normal data. I need to put it in a less expensive database, not hide it. I also do not want to manage my own data and prefer to leave it up to a cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your questions and comments, you might not find the perfect solution.   You want free or dirt cheap storage, and you want to have your data available online.

There is only one solution I can see feasible:

1. Stick with MongoDB.  SimpleDB does not allow you to store documents, only key-value pairs.
2. You could create a separate collection for your history.  Use a cloud service that gives you a free tier. For example, http://MongoLab.com gives you 240Mb free tier.
3. If you exceed the free tier, you can look at discarding the oldest data, moving it to offline storage, or start paying for what you are using.

If you data grows a lot you will have to make the decision whether to pay for it, keep it available online or offline, or discard it.

Comment: I'm already using http://MongoLab.com and am looking for something significantly cheaper to store my old data. I'm using them to store my live data... At this point I'm thinking of hosting the database myself and just backing up to S3.

Comment: But by doing that you will not have the reliability of an online system and you will be paying for the server where you will be hosting your data offline.     The point in the answer was to highlight that you will be paying for the solution one way or the other, that is, paying for the hosting, or paying for your own servers, or paying by sacrificing availability if you have an offline storage.  You just need to prioritize what feature you put on top:  Availability, or cost.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a lot of large objects (BLOBS or CLOBS), you can also store the 'non-indexed' data separate from the database. This keeps the database both cheap and fast. The large objects can be retrieved from any cheap storage when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant.com is pretty cool for hosting your DB in the cloud and it uses Big Couch which is a nosql thing. I'm using it for my social site in the works as Couch DB (Big Couch) similar has an open ended structure and you talk to it via JSON. Its pretty awesome stuff but so weird to move from SQL to using Map-Reduce but once you do its worth it. I did some research because I'm a .NET guy for a long time but moving to Linux and Node.js partly out of bordom and the love of JavaScript. These things just fit together because Node.js is all JavaScript on the backend and talks seemlessly to Couch DB and the whole thing scales like crazy.